# Change label text in widget via mainwindow

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals, qlabel

I am quite new to programming GUIs with Python... as any experienced programmer will soon find out. The program I am working on is supposed to have a MainWindow with a nested QTab widget which in turn holds serveral seperate widgets. I have been trying for some time now to get the following piece of simplified code to work. Unfortunately I get the AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'label_00'.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QAction, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QTabWidget, QToolBar
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
#from PyQt5 import QtGui 
#from LftQAFs import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Light")
        self.setGeometry(100,100,750,120)

        toolbar = QToolBar("Tool Bar")
        toolbar.setIconSize(QSize(24,24))
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)

        button_loadLftQAF = QAction("Load Data", self)
        toolbar.addAction(button_loadLftQAF)  
        button_loadLftQAF.triggered.connect(SubWidget.funcTest)

        self.setCentralWidget(SubWidget())

        self.show()

class SubWidget(QWidget):

    signalFuncTest = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.layout_main = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.label_00 = QLabel("Label")
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.label_00)

        self.setLayout(self.layout_main)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def funcTest(self):        
        print("works")
        self.label_00.setText('Changed Label')


app = QApplication([])

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

I would be very happy to get a solution to this problem as well as a hint to what topic I should read up on to understand what I did wrong. Any structural advise is also highly appreciated...:)

Thanks, Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SubWidget.funcTest` is an instance method, which means you need to create an instance of `SubWidget` first, e.g. `sub_widget = SubWidget()`, and connect `sub_widget.funcTest` to `button_loadLftQAF.triggered` instead of `SubWidget.funcTest`, e.g.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    ...

    def initUI(self):

        ...

        sub_widget = SubWidget(self)
        button_loadLftQAF.triggered.connect(sub_widget.funcTest)

        self.setCentralWidget(sub_widget)

        ...
```